# django rest framework - tricky is_valid()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with a serializer class from the django rest framework:

```
class CustomFields(serializers.Serializer):
    channel = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    show = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
```

The tricky part is a piece of code I use somewhere else:

```
        json_acceptable_string = self.custom_fields_json.replace("'", "\"")
        data_dict = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
        serializer = CustomFields(data=data_dict)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.status = Status.COMPLETE
        else:
            print serializer.errors
```

This is tricky because It gives inconsistent results for the `is_valid()` function. With the same data it returns `true` sometimes and `false` in others. The trickiest thing is that the `serializer.errors` is always empty. Moreover, when I add the `else` to the `if`, the is valid begins to give me true always.

I really don't understand why, it looks like is is_valid() function is asynchronous.

Would you have any tip to help me solve is inconsistent behavior?

Thanks

Comment: What does your data_dict looks like ?

Comment: there is not enough information, please show 2  scenarios where you get 2 outputs based on same data